# JavaFX file downloading using http and other alternatives technology?

Tags: java, browser, jxbrowser

I am working on a project that requires a web browser being embedded in Java.
I have tried JavaFX, but it does not support the downloading of files using http.
I have read this [article](http://www.zenjava.com/2011/11/14/file-downloading-in-javafx-2-0-over-http/). This article show how to write download script but the download link is not shown in the front-end either, so I do not really know the download link. As a result, JavaFX cannot be my option unless there is a way that itself support download using http.

I have also looked at the [dj nativeswing project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/).
I am wonder does dj native swing support file downloading default?
I can answer by my own, it seems does not.

I also found [this](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser).
The jxbrowser support download and upload well, but it is not free >.<

Comment: What's wrong with the technique in the [post you linked](http://www.zenjava.com/2011/11/14/file-downloading-in-javafx-2-0-over-http/)? That seems to be a full and comprehensive guide.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, they are, but they are not the stuff that I look for

Comment: Could you explain what, specifically, that tutorial misses that you need? Preferably by editing your post to precisely state what the tutorial does different to what you need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jxbrowser.
http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser

If your project is opensource, the jxbrowser is free too.
I believe it is most mature technology that can embed web browser in java, even better than javafx